# Check if a user likes a post/status message using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When getting a post comments list using POST_ID/comments, each comment contains a Boolean field named "user_likes" that tells me if the user likes the comment or not (this is how i decide which button to display like/unlike).

When getting the list of posts the post itself does not contain this field. I can still post to POST_ID/likes and DELETE to this address to change the like state, but there is no indication of the current state of the like.

Am i missing something? Is there an other way to determine the like state of the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could query the FQL "likes" table for the particular user or the object id in question.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

Alternatively (I'm guessing you  have read_stream permission here) you could query the following table

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

Using the graph api explorer try running this query

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20post_id%2C%20likes%20FROM%20stream%20where%20source_id%20%3D%20me()

make sure you grant the read_stream permission! There are obviously more fields you could retur as well, and you can replace "me()" with a different user_id, but then you might need to use the app access token

Comment: meaning i will have to do a query for each post to see if the user likes it. that is a lot of queries. Is there a way to get this bool field when requesting me/home as part of the returned data ?

Comment: Ok, you could try https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3Dselect%20object_id%20from%20like%20where%20user_id%20%3D%20me() that should give you the object_id of things you have liked. You could store these in a local variable and check it against the object in question. Make sure you add () after the "me" in the query above as SO is removing it from the link

Comment: This should return the whole list? I get a list of 50-60 items and i believe that i clicked the like button more then that...

Comment: @BrunoLemos this answer was also from 2012 when it was relevant at the time

Answer (score 1):

If you query the posts using /me/feed (for example) you can influence what fields are returned by adding the "fields" query param. In this case you can use "likes". This contains an array with all likes. You have to check if the user is a member of this array. The returned data by the FQL-variant mentioned by TommyBs is a little prettier (as often with FQL) though.

Example:
/me/feed?fields=id,likes will return all posts ids and who liked them.

Comment: when i am running this query i am getting only 1 user who liked the post and the likes count. for example, i can see a post with 1 person name/id and the likes count is on 574.

Comment: Strange, for me (and my own feed) it displays all the people who liked it. - But as I said: Use TommyBs solution. Then you don't even have to use /me/home anymore - just use one FQL query. If you are stuck with the Graph API for some reason there's always "SELECT ... FROM stream where post_id in (209435094, 34032235, 23407249025, ....)" - so you can use one query for all posts.

Comment: Now that FQL is deprecated, I think this is the only solutions nowadays.

Comment: If the post has a lot (lets say, 1K+) likes, it has to return all of them? :/